# Show that $T^3= T \implies \text{Diagonalizability}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem
Let $W$ be a vector space over a field $\mathcal{F}$. Also let $T: W\to W$. Show that if $T^3=T$, then $T$ is diagonalizable.

Idea;
I would like to prove this using the fact, that  a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimum polynomials splits into distinct linear factors. Any hint on how to do that?

Comment: The minimal polynomial divides $T^3 -T= T(T-I)(T+I)$ by Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: If $T^3=T$, then $T^3-T=0$, so $T$ satisfies the polynomial $p(x) = x^3-x$. Go from there.

Comment: The minimal polynomial divides $X^3-X$ so it has to split into distinct linear factors since $X^3-X$ does.

Comment: @Arturo Magiadin You are right, I corrected my comment

Comment: @Zanzag: The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem still has nothing to do with this. It tells you that the transformation satisfies its characteristic polynomial. How is that relevant here?